# jQuery Passthrough on Click

Tags: jquery, event-passthrough

I was wondering if it's possible to ignore the execution of a jQuery function on the second click so that I can create a passthrough, but only when the user clicks on "Yes" on a confirmation click. I have the confirmation box showing, but can't figure out a way to do this.

```
$(function()
{    
    $(".msgbox-confirm").live("click", function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.msgbox("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this element?", {
            type: "confirm",
            buttons: [
                { type: "submit", value: "Yes" },
                { type: "submit", value: "No" }
            ]
        }, function(result)
        {
            if (result == "Yes") {
                // passthrough code goes here!
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method for your element, so next time it won't fire up.

```
    $(".msgbox-confirm").unbind("click");
```

Comment: How do I continue executing the button? I have PHP code attached to it.

Comment: Essentially I would like to submit "Yes" in the code above.

Comment: @user1408643 You can use a global flag, which states if the "Yes" was already pressed, but that's bad codestyle.
I guess the better approach will be if you will attach just new handler for "click" event.

Comment: @user1408643 Basically you have function doThePassthroughRoutine(). When user hits "Yes", do the $(".msgbox-confirm").live("click", function() { doThePassthroughRoutine(); });

Comment: I think I should change the question to how do I use jQuery to submit a form. I would like to know how I can submit the "Yes" click.